# HTTParty adding 25 to % in query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, httparty

I am creating a ruby on rails application using HTTParty.  I create a request using this method

```
query   = { :flyFrom => "london_gb",:dateFrom => "02%2F11%2F2015"}
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.blahblah.com/flights', :query => query)
```

However HTTParty seems to encode % signs as %25.  So the request looks like this:

https://api.blahblah.com/flights?flyfrom=london&dateFrom==02%252F11%252F2015

As you can see the difference is:

```
02%2F11%2F2015
02%252F11%252F2015
```

My API expects the dates to be in a particular format, so is complaining about this.  Does anyone know how you can get HTTParty to encode these characters correctly so that it sends just a % rather than %25?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted answer based on the additional comments.

["%25" is the correct URL encoding for "%"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4). So HTTParty is encoding the percent.

However, ["%2F" is the URL encoding for "/"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). So if you intend to send "02%2F11%2F2015" over the wire then you probably want to pass the unencoded version to HTTParty: "02/11/2015".

Comment: Hmm... Do you know how I could get HTTParty not to add these to the query parameters themselves?  As currently

 "GET /flights?v=2&sort=price&asc=1&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&flyFrom=london_gb&to=new-york_us&dateFrom=02%2F11%2F2015&dateTo=02%2F11%2F2015&typeFlight=return&returnTo=04%2F11%2F2015&limit=1&curr=gbp works....  But GET /flights?v=2&sort=price&asc=1&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&flyFrom=london_gb&to=new-york_us&dateFrom=02%252F11%252F2015&dateTo=02%252F11%252F2015&typeFlight=return&returnTo=04%252F11%252F2015&limit=1&curr=gbp doesn't

Comment: The difference being the second query has 25 after the %

Comment: You probably cannot get around url encoding, make sure to decode it again and you'll be fine!

Comment: It's not my API though, so it rejects my input... If I request the URL with the parameters like this however it works..  response = HTTParty.get('https://api.blahblah.com/flights?flyFrom=london_gb&dateFrom=02%2F11%2F2015)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, @Jack. Updated my answer to take your comments into consideration.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it, I was already encoding the "/" which were being encoded themselves to represent the %